# CSS z-index cross-browser issue for links inside a absolutely positioned DIV

Tags: html, css, layout, cross-browser

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/mithun/nuF2Q/1/

I've the HTML structure

```
<div id='slider'>
    <ul>
        <li> 
            <a class='pride' href="i1.html"> Item 1 </a>
            <div class='info'> 
                <a class='roar' href="i1.html"> Description 2 </a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li> 
            <a class='pride' href="i2.html"> Item 2 </a>
                        <div class='info'> 
                <a class='roar' href="i1.html"> Description 1 </a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class='pride' href="i3.html"> Item 3 </a>
             <div class='info'> 
                <a class='roar' href="i1.html"> Description 3 </a>
            </div>
           </li>
        <li>
            <a class='pride' href="i4.html"> Item 4 </a> 
                        <div class='info'> 
                <a class='roar' href="i1.html"> Description 4 </a>
            </div>
         </li>
    </ul>
 <div>
```

and CSS

```
#slider {
    width : 400px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #bcd;
    background-color: #def;
    position:relative;
    z-index:0 !important;
}

#slider ul{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    list-style:none;
}

#slider ul li {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px
    list-style:none;
    width:100px;
    z-index:10;
}
#slider ul li a.pride {
    color: #333;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 2px 0px 2px 10px;
}
#slider ul li.active a.pride,
#slider ul li:hover a.pride {
    background-color: #ffff7c;
}    

#slider ul li div.info {
    background-color: #9ab;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    right: 0;
    top:0;
    z-index:-5;
}
#slider ul li.active div.info,
#slider ul li:hover div.info {
    display:block;
}
#slider ul li div.info a.roar{
    color: #0a0;
    display:block;
    width: 280px;
    height: 80px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index:10;
}
```

Issue is links inside the Div's are not click able, actually they are behind the UL

-- update

It happens only in Webkit/Gecko browsers

Opera and IE are displaying it correctly

Comment: its fine for me in opera 11. Any browser specification

Comment: yup, it happens only in Chrome and Firefox browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixes it for me in Firefox and Chrome:

```
<div id='slider'>
    <ul style="width:100px">
```

`100px` <strike>might not be</strike> is the optimum width.

Answer (score 1):

here

http://jsfiddle.net/nuF2Q/4/

what you had done wrong was settting the z-index to -5; for `div.info` which made it get under the ul element which prevented you from clicking the links...

so what i did was change it to 5 and then set the `a.prid` links position to relative and add a index of 6 so it would overlapp the `div.info` element

Comment: How is that `#slider ul li a.pride {` fix worked, can you please explain this

Comment: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed). so i have to set `#slider ul li a.pride` position to relative and set a higher z-index then what the `div.info` has to make it overlapp

Answer (score 0):

z-index only has an effect when the element has the 'position' property set--so try putting 'position: relative' on the elements with z-index that don't already have the property.

In addition, elements naturally stack in the order in which they appear in the source. When elements overlap, the once that appear later will be stacked on top of the ones that appear earlier. So if you remove the z-index property from everything on the stylesheet, you should also have the desired result.